Save game files
I recently decided to embark on the adventure of reverse engineering game save files and I am trying to modify the Eternium game data, I have tried to see similarities between the different saves but the only thing I have found is that they start with "kdata1004". I have tried using HxD to find values and I have been asking ChatGPT. It's probably almost impossible but I leave the files in case someone can think of something.
The structure i choose for the file names is as follows (the original was player.player.dat):
player.player.bak<number of save>.<gems>.<gold>.dat
there can be saves in the middle of these but let's say they are in chronological order from 0 to 4.
As I said the files are probably encrypted or encoded with some technique so I would be interested to know if anyone knows how.
Finally I would like to point out that although all the save files start with "kdata1004." there are game files that start with "kdata1002." so that must mean something.
I leave here a link to the files and the game in stempor if you want to analyze the files on your own.
Save files
Eternium on Steam
